# Kubuntu 16.04 freezing upon login

Tags: permissions, graphics, kubuntu, login, amd-graphics

I have just recently updated the permissions (allowing Plex media server complete access) to my Videos, Music, and Pictures folder in my home directory. Before that, I had (attempted to) updated the permissions (with the same user) to my entire home folder. But after i had done both things, and rebooted my PC, as I attempted to log in it went blank. After a bit of diggin' on the Web, I found and used the following commands:

> rm ~/.local/share/kscreen
>
> sudo killall sddm

But alas, it only made it worse. I couldn't even get past the login page after I did it, even after rebooting and deleting the ~/.Xauthority file and rebooting AGAIN and trying to login.

Can anybody help? Thanks!

Kubuntu 16.04, dual booting with Windows 10 Home.

AMD A6-5200 Laptop APU with Radeon R3 Graphics (512MB Graphics Memory)

19" AOC Monitor in use, when it broke, but disconnected at the time of this writing.